# converting node inheritance to hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera, hierarchy

I'm working on moving over a node inheritance tree to hiera. Presently working on the *hierarchy*. Prior to hiera, my nodes had a hierarchy as such

```
base
  pre-prod
    qa
      nodes
    staging
      nodes
    development
      nodes
  prod
    nodes
```

Now I'm trying to get the same tier with hiera. Starting out I have this

```
:hierarchy:
  - base
  - "%{environment}"
  - "%{clientcert}"
```

but I need another level to capture *pre-prod* and *prod*. My thought would be to add an entry to *puppet.conf*, something like

```
[agent]
realm = pre-prod
```

then

```
:hierarchy:
  - base
  - "%{realm}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - "%{clientcert}"
```

A couple of questions

1. Are you allowed to place arbitrary properties into *puppet.conf*?
2. Will hiera see the *realm* property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that on the client side, with a custom fact instead of a `puppet.conf` setting.  However, I'd say do it on the server side, in the Hiera data.  The trick that I use for something similar is as follows:

1. Set something in the Hiera data at the `clientcert` level, for each server.  In your case:

   ```
   realm: "pre-prod"
   ```
2. Grab that variable into global scope via Hiera in `site.pp`, before your `hiera_include`:

   ```
   $realm = hiera(realm)

   hiera_include(classes)
   ```
3. The variable's been fetched from the `clientcert.yaml` file, and will now be used in the lookups that occur from your `hiera_include`, pulling from `pre-prod.yaml` based on the `"%{realm}"` config in your hierarchy.

Comment: Very nice looking, I'll give it a spin tomorrow!